# PHP: Text explode() problem

Tags: php, split, explode

I have a problem with explode() function. I use the function to explode strings like "Name: Replica" but sometimes in the string has 2 or more colons ( ":" ) and there is the problem because my script is:
Example: "**Name: replica:replica2:replica3**"

```
$explode = explode(":", $string);
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`field_1`, `field_2`) VALUES ('".$explode[0]."', '".$explode[1]."')";
```

And I need any solution for this problem. Because when I split the string after first colon ( ":" ) the second part must be the last part.

Regards,
George!

P.s. - Sorry for my English.

Comment: how do you know which colon it should be split at?

Comment: 2 or more colons meaning: `name:replica:blah:bluh` OR `name::replica`?

Comment: 2 or more colons means: Name: asdasd:asdasd:ahsiduashd:replica:rep2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to use the 'limit' (third) argument to `explode()`:

```
list($attribute, $value) = explode(":", $string, 2);
```

That will make sure you only get two results.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2):

Use the optional third `$limit` parameter to `explode()`:

```
$explode = explode(":", $string, 2);
```

This tells `explode()` to return an array with at most 2 elements, putting all subsequent colons into the second string fragment returned. Note, according to your examples you should be using a colon plus a space:

```
$explode = explode(": ", $string, 2);
```

But maybe that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

edited as suggested by @Jon Nalley. Note that *limit* (3rd parameter) is only supported by PHP 5.x

```
list($attribute, $value) = explode(":", $string, 2);
```

Comment: I was try your method but abortively... This is my code:

`$string = "Name: asdasd: asdasd:asdasdad";
list($attribute, $value) = explode(":", $string);
echo $attribute.$value;`

Try it and U'll see.